# Github repo, deleting a folder or sub module

Tags: python, git, module, directory, repository

I created a git repo for my python assignment. I commit few things and also pushed but I don’t want them in my git hub repo anymore. how to remove? Its PayPoll sub module or a directory not sure as i made a directory but in git hub everything is under a green file, like my code, its results everything. I don’t want i don’t want it that way. There should be PyPoll then inside PyPoll Resources, Analysis and main.py

I tried `git rm -r`
Then commit it
Even push